# How can I tint a nine-patch image?

Tags: android

I've learned how to tint an image when it's pressed by adding an OnTouchListener in which I call setColorFilter on the image.

I've learned how to use nine-patch images as the background for Buttons and ImageButtons.

The problem is, nine-path images don't stretch if they're the src for an ImageButton, and the tint has no effect on the background image.

How can I tint a nine-patch ImageButton when it's pressed? Any suggestions?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I think you'd have better results by making a separate asset for each button state. For instance, you can make a drawable xml file like this:

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/btn_pressed" 
        android:state_pressed="true" />
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/btn_focused"
        android:state_pressed="false"
        android:state_focused="true" />
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/btn_default"
        android:state_focused="false"
        android:state_pressed="false" />
</selector>
```

Then create a style for your buttons like this:

```
<style name="PushButton">
    <item name="android:background">@drawable/btn</item>
</style>
```

Then you should be able to style your image buttons and set the src to whatever image you want.

```
<ImageButton
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@drawable/icon"
        style="@style/PushButton" />
```

Comment: So you are saying that a nine-path image CANNOT be tinted, so I should use a separate image for the pressed state? Thanks anyway... if anyone does know of a way to add a tinting effect dynamically to a nine-patch image, that would be awesome.

Comment: Unfortunately, no better approach seems to be possible... I've found no way to tint a nine-patch image, so Krylez' suggestion of manually making different images for each state appears to be the only solution.

Answer (score 12):

I know it's an old question but it seems that it's the only one on this topic.

You can tint nine patch images by creating an xml resource file containing a nine patch node and a tint node. Example :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<nine-patch xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:src="@drawable/nine_patch_image"
        android:tint="@android:color/black"/>
```

You may then reference this file in your background attributes :

```
<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/some_id"
    android:background="@drawable/xml_filename">
```

Hope this will help someone

Answer (score 2):

So I'm 3 years late but I found a way to do this.
(I'm using Xamarin so excuse any C# formatting I miss)

```
@Override
protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas)
    {
        NinePatchDrawable bg = (NinePatchDrawable)getResources().getDrawable(R.Drawable.whatev);
        bg.setBounds(0, 0, getWidth(), getHeight());
        bg.setColorFilter(new PorterDuffColorFilter(color, PorterDuff.Mode.MULTIPLY));
        bg.draw(canvas);
        base.onDraw(canvas);
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Another option, is using backgroundTint (available on API21 and above):

```
            <TextView
            android:id="@+id/chat_bubble_text"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@drawable/left_bubble"
            android:backgroundTint="@color/main_color"
            android:gravity="center_vertical"
            android:minWidth="200dp"
            android:textColor="@android:color/white"
            android:visibility="visible"
            tools:text="message" />
```

Answer (score 0):

I found one way you can kinda sorta of do this. Using a purely gray-scale, semi-transparent 9-patch image as your button background, wrap the button in a view group which has your tint color as *its* background like this:

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="#F00"
    android:orientation="vertical" >
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/my_butt"
        android:background="@drawable/my_semi_transparent_gray_9_patch"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="I'm a tinted 9-patch button!" />
</LinearLayout>
```

The main problem is that if your image has transparent edges, the tint color will show through where you don't want it, but if your image edges used a fully opaque color that matched the background of whatever container you put this thing in, it might work well enough. You also might need to write your own selector that changes those background colors for each state you care about. I'm not recommending this approach but maybe it will help someone. I agree that it's a shame that tinting isn't built into the 9-patch design because it feels stupid to maintain a bunch of identical images that differ only in tint, especially when you multiply that by a number of different drawable sizes. Even better would be for Android to natively support SVG. I've modified the open-source "svg-android" library so that with the right art I only need a single image that can be stretched and tinted as needed.

Comment: Nice button id you got there :)